# Android Studio can't find package when import org.robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am using butterknife package:8.5.1, when I want to add robolectric, gradle says com.google.guava has conflit:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.guava:guava' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (18.0) and test app (20.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

I checked the dependencies, and because ButterKnife is using `guava` 18, so I use

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    }
}
```

try to avoid, now gradle will build without errors.

However, when I want to use the package, Android Studio always complains at

> import org.robolectric.Robolectric;

It says it can't find `org.robolectric`. I have no idea what's going on, can someone help? Thank a lot.

Then I also tried

```
exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
```

also the same result

I suspect it has something to do with `com.google.guava`, but I can't understand why it can't find the package. I can see robolectric package under "external libraries"

Comment: Show us the full gradle file. How did you add Robolectric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I found it's because my test is under androidTest folder, not test, which causes the package unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
in

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4'     // instead of TestCompile
}
```

It worked for me.